# Exact arctangent of product of tangents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Calculate $x$, if $$\tan(x)=\tan9\tan69\tan33$$

(Using sexagesimal degrees) Since $\tan3x=\tan(60-x)\tan x \tan(60+x)$:
\begin{align*}
\tan27&=\tan69\tan9\tan51\\
\implies\tan27\tan39&=\tan69\tan9
\end{align*}

So the problem is equivalent to calculating $x$ in
$$\tan(x)=\tan27\tan33\tan39$$
But thats all my progress so far. Interestingly enough, the answer is $x=15$. Is there some way tu constructively solve the equation? If not, a straightforward proof of $\tan(15)=\tan9\tan69\tan33$ would be nice too.

Comment: **Hint:** $27=60-33$.

Comment: another hint: $33 = 30 + 3$

Comment: @Lucian  So $\tan99=\tan27\tan33\tan93\implies \tan81\tan3=\tan27\tan33$. I don't see what to do next.

Comment: $\tan99^\circ=-\dfrac1{\tan9^\circ}$.

Comment: @Lucian Reordering the equation, we would go back to $\tan 9=\tan 27 \tan 3 \tan 87$, it is exactly the result of the triple angle identity with $x=3$. I think we are going in circles. How is tha $\tan 15$ supposed to appear?

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/0/5/e05e0cfd3a6dc78847105d44fedd6d8b.png This may help

Comment: With tangent addition formulae you can compute the closed forms of the tangents.

Comment: Interesting! So ultimately after doing some serious computations we would be able to prove it. But I am quite convinced that was not the inteded way of doing things (it would be a correct solution though :) )

Comment: Would you please tell me how to get the 2nd equation in the answer.  (Also, are you assuming that x is an acute angle?)

Comment: @user84413 $\tan27=\tan9\tan51\tan69\implies\tan39\tan27=\tan9\tan69$. So $\tan x=\tan27\tan33\tan39$. And $\tan9=\tan3\tan57\tan63\implies \tan81\tan3=\tan57\tan63$. So $x=\tan81\tan3\tan39$.

Comment: @user84413 You're welcome!. The problem as it was posed didn't force $x$ to be acute, so being more formal, $x$ would have the values $180^\circ n+15^\circ\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ if we consider all the cases :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \tan(x)=\tan(9)\tan(69)\tan(33) $$ 
$$ \tan(x) = \frac{\tan(39)\tan(3)}{\tan(9)} $$ 
Thus, 
$$ \tan^2(x) = \tan(3)\tan(33)\tan(39)\tan(69) $$ 
$$ \tan^2(x) = \tan(3)\tan(3-36)\tan(3-72)\tan(3+36) $$ 
$$ \tan^2(x)\tan(75) = \tan(3-72)\tan(3-36)\tan(3)\tan(3+36)\tan(3+72) $$

I will now show that ,

$$ \tan(5x)= \tan(x-72)\tan(x-36)\tan(x)\tan(x+36)\tan(x+72) $$

Let $z=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, and $ \omega = \cos(36)+i\sin(36) $
Then, $$ \tan(x) = -\frac{i(z^2-1)}{2(z^2+1)} $$
Similarly we can get $\tan(x-36),\tan(x-72),\tan(x+36),\tan(x+72) $ 
and then multiply . We very easily get the above identity. 
So, we have 
$$ \tan^2(x)=\tan^2(15) \implies x=15 $$

Comment: Where did you use $\omega$?

Comment: to write, tan(x-36),tan(x+36)... 
in terms of complex number (for example for tan(x-36), replace z by z/w